# How does experience work for skills in world of tanks?

Tags: world-of-tanks

I've got a tank that has just reached 100% crew experience level and, all excited, I set some skills to advance.

My Commander had a skill "Signal Boosting" and I received 500 experience points for a match; all my experience is being sent into "accelerate crew training" and it says that I only need 72 xp to "Upgrade Skill" (estimated one battle)

But after the 500 xp my skills only went up to 12%, what's happening here? Even with 500 xp divided amoungst the 4 crew that would seem to be >72 xp needed!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "72 xp needed" means that it will take another 72xp to upgrade the skill to the next percentage point. So if your skill was at 11%, then it would take 72xp to get the skill to 12%

Too increase the 1st skill perk to 100% from 0%, you will need a total of  total of 210,484 XP.

The [World of Tanks wiki](http://wiki.wargaming.net/en/Crew#Experience_Required_to_Increase_Training_Level) describes it in detail:

"It is important to recognize two facts about the amount of XP required to increase Training Level.

First, the total amount of experience required to achieve a 100% Training Level in the 1st Skill or Perk is double that required to increase the Major Qualification to 100%. This doubling occurs each time with each new Skill or Perk. Training the 2nd Skill or Perk to 100% requires double the amount of XP that the 1st Skill or Perk requires, the 3rd requires double the XP of the 2nd and so on. To increase the Training Level of the:"

```
    Major Qualification from 0% to 100% requires a total of 105,242 XP.
    1st Skill or Perk from 0% to 100% requires a total of 210,484 XP.
    2nd Skill or Perk from 0% to 100% requires a total of 420,128 XP.
    3rd Skill or Perk from 0% to 100% requires a total of 840,255 XP.
```

Comment: Blimey! That is a rather lot of experience!
Thanks for the excellent answer however

Comment: @Rob if you use one crew on different tanks (for example, from PzKpfw III through all tiers to E-50 ausf M) it is not so much. I have 4th perk on E-50 ausf M and E-100

Comment: Thanks @spyder ; I'm working my way up the french SPG tiers, so that's helpful

Comment: So when experience reaches 100% I get some sort of "base" skill for that crew member?

Comment: It depends per skill, some skills start working as soon as they're at 1% (although less effective than at 100%), for others you have to wait until they are at 100%